# using same value for radioButton when posting to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a 2 `radioButtons` in my `layout`. One is for `yes` and the other is for `no` when asked if insured or not. When I click my `save` button and the data posts to `firestore`, it shows both `NO INSURED` and `YES INSURED`. The way I have my code set up is why it's that way but what I want to do is have one source where if the person clicks `yes` or `no` then in `firestore` I will have `Insured : Yes` or `Insured : No`. I will post my code down below

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.dynamic.ObjectWrapper;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProviderSignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String KEY_FNAME = "First Name";
    private static final String KEY_LNAME = "Last Name";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "Address";
    private static final String KEY_SPINNER_VALUE = "Spinner Value";
    private static final String KEY_FIXED= "Fixed Rate";
    private static final String KEY_HOURLY = "Hourly Rate";
    private static final String KEY_AGE_VALE= "Age Value";
    private static final String KEY_DOLLAR_VALUE = "Dollar Value";
    private static final String KEY_YES_INSURED = "Yes Insured";
    private static final String KEY_NO_INSURED = "No Insured";


    private EditText fName;
    private EditText lName;
    private EditText address;
    private Spinner my_spinner;
    private RadioButton fixedRadioButton;
    private RadioButton hourlyRadioButton;
    private EditText ageEditText;
    private EditText dollarEditText;
    private RadioButton yesButton;
    private RadioButton noButton;


    // Reference to firestore database
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.provider_signup);


        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.provider_choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // FireStore Storage for Provider

        fName = findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lName = findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        address = findViewById(R.id.Address);
        my_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        fixedRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.fixedRadioButton);
        hourlyRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.hourlyRadioButton);
        ageEditText = findViewById(R.id.ageEditText);
        dollarEditText = findViewById(R.id.dollarEditText);
        yesButton = findViewById(R.id.yesRadioButton);
        noButton = findViewById(R.id.noRadioButton);



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(ProviderSignUp.this,PreSignUp.class));
        finish();
    }

    // These two methods below are for the spinner in the ProviderSignUp
    @Override
    // Will show a toast message after user selects spinner item
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }



        String fname = fName.getText().toString();
        String lname = lName.getText().toString();
        String my_address = address.getText().toString();
        String spinner = my_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String fixed_radioButton = fixedRadioButton.getText().toString();
        String hourly_Radiobutton = hourlyRadioButton.getText().toString();
        String age = ageEditText.getText().toString();
        String dollar = dollarEditText.getText().toString();
        String yes_button = yesButton.getText().toString();
        String no_button = noButton.getText().toString();

        Map<String,Object> myMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        myMap.put(KEY_FNAME,fname);
        myMap.put(KEY_LNAME,lname);
        myMap.put(KEY_ADDRESS, my_address);
        myMap.put(KEY_FIXED, fixed_radioButton);
        myMap.put(KEY_HOURLY, hourly_Radiobutton);
        myMap.put(KEY_AGE_VALE, age);
        myMap.put(KEY_DOLLAR_VALUE, dollar);
        myMap.put(KEY_YES_INSURED, yes_button);
        myMap.put(KEY_NO_INSURED, no_button);
        myMap.put(KEY_SPINNER_VALUE , spinner);

        db.collection("demoProviders").document("First Provider")
                .set(myMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(ProviderSignUp.this, "User Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ProviderSignUp.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to use a ToggleButton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First thing first,

> When I click my `save` button and the data posts to `firestore`

This is not happening according to your code. You should use `OnClickListener` method to implement your thought. I suggest going through this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#ClickListener).

---

### Second thing second,

Hope, you are using `RadioGroup` for your `RadioButton`. That won't allow more than one `RadioButton` to be selected at a single time. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton) is how you can implement `RadioGroup`.

---

### Last thing last,

Use a single key to store a boolean value instead of storing multiple key-value pairs for `RadioButton` state in `Firestore`. Try this :

```
if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.yesRadioButton){
    myMap.put("isInsured", true);
} else {
    myMap.put("isInsured", false);
}
```

instead of this :

```
myMap.put(KEY_YES_INSURED, yes_button);
myMap.put(KEY_NO_INSURED, no_button);
```

If you do all the mentioned steps correctly your database should store one value for your `RadioButton` states. Try and let us know if this worked or not.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This is just what I needed!

Comment: Glad you liked it...Happy coding!

Comment: @lets0code hey! Were you able to store the radio button to Firestore? Can I ask you some questions?

Comment: @DipayanRay Hi. I wonder if you can help with my post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73735957/save-and-update-radiobutton-response-correctly-java