# How to save radio button value into Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, save, androidx, android-radiobutton

I've tried to find this kind of tutorial in YouTube but I cant seem to find it. Most of the storing radio button value tutorial is only for Firebase Realtime Database but not for Firebase Cloud Firestore

Comment: Do you find the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439672/using-same-value-for-radiobutton-when-posting-to-firestore) to be useful?

Comment: Thank you. It is useful but I actually have come up with a way of ".getText().toString()"

Comment: I'm glad that you've fount the post shared to be useful. But I don't understand if your last comment is a statement or a question. If you've found an answer to your own question I encourage you to post your answer with the community.