# Save and update radiobutton response correctly java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save the radio button user response in Firestore under the UID. I have two choices `yes` and `no` to the question. It only works one time that the user selects a choice with a button pressed but if the user wants to change the answer it does not update (replace the old response).

I am wondering if anyone can help so that the selected response can be updated.

```
buttonfor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String yes = yesButton.getText().toString();
                String no = yesButton.getText().toString();

               Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.question_a1) {
                    user.put("I am wiling to participate", yes);
                } else if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.question_a2){
                    user.put("I am wiling to participate", no);
                }

                userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                fStore.collection("users").document(userID).set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(question.this, "User Response Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(question.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

In addition, I also tried but the response does not update in Firestore

```
 if (yesButton.isChecked()){
            user.put("I am wiling to participate", yes);
        } else if (noButton.isChecked()){
            user.put("I am wiling to participate", no);
        }
```

And with `update` instead of `set` also did not work...

```
fStore.collection("users").document(userID).update(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi Alex, thanks for the response. Not yet. I also tried using if statement for `is.clicked` for the two radio buttons but still can't update. Can I edit with more codes and ask you for help?

Comment: So you're actually looking for having the radio button set, according to what you have stored in the database? And each time you select, you need to update that in the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes! I have a button `buttonfor`. After each time the radio button is selected and clicked and button `buttonfor`, I'd like to update the value in the Firestore database

Comment: And each time, you open the app, would you like to read it first, so it can be set according to what already exists in the database, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes! Each time when the app is open, the user select a radio button and store there. If the user changes the selection, it should be updated. Would it be wise to stored the old response as well? At the moment, my code only save once and did not update / stack a new response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, first, you have to create a layout that contains two radio buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/yesRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/noRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then inside your activity, you have to find them by id and attach a real-time listener. Assuming that your Firestore schema looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- participate: true
            |
            --- //other fields
```

Here is the code:

Define them as members of the class (global variables):

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference uidRef = db.collection("users").document(uid);
```

Add inside onCreate:

```
RadioButton yesRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.yesRadioButton);
RadioButton noRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.noRadioButton);
uidRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }

        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            Boolean participate = snapshot.getBoolean("participate");
            if(participate != null) {
                if (participate) {
                    yesRadioButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    noRadioButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is to code for attaching a click listener on each radio button:

```
yesRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (yesRadioButton.isChecked()) {
            updateParticipate(true);
        }
    }
});
noRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (noRadioButton.isChecked()) {
            updateParticipate(false);
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the method which is responsible for the update:

```
void updateParticipate(boolean participate) {
    Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
    update.put("participate", participate);
    uidRef.update(update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated: " + participate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for your time! I am trying your suggestions and I will update you soon.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Hey. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am trying your suggestion and encounter one problem for this line ` boolean participate = snapshot.getBoolean("participate");` I think this line assumed that the participate field is created, which does not apply if the user is answering the first time? I got an error saying `ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference`

Comment: In that case, you should check `participate` against nullity, as in my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks Alex. And I am still getting error if I check null with `participate` and I got `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'null'`

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. It should be `Boolean participate`, the Boolean class, not the primitive.  See `B` capital? Try it again and tell me if it works.

Comment: All good Alex! Works perfectly! And I wonder I can store specific answer: `yes`, `no` or more than 2 options? In that case, `Boolean` might not be ideal and I have to get the string? Sorry if that's another question - might be I should try it myself or open another post? Because I was hoping to get the `string` rather than true/false but I think you have helped a lot Alex!

Comment: In your question, you specified only two options, yes and no. So doesn't make sense to use a String, but a boolean value. If you however have more than two options, then yes, you should store them as a String.

Comment: And yes, give it a try yourself. If you have a hard time implementing it, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I tried using the same logic and I was only able to store the string once. The `addSnapshotListener` does not seem to update. I posted another question and I hope its more clear? Not too sure if you have time to help but I really appreciated your help Alex! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73791063/listening-radio-buttons-and-saving-the-string-results-in-firestore-java

Comment: @swiftlearneer I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not able to comment yet!
If your question is not solved yet, please may you provide more code because per my check on the code snippet you provided I cannot detect where the error is coming from.

Comment: It's best practice to use comments for clarifying or asking for information and to submit answers with possible solutions.

Comment: @RafaelZasas Hi! I wonder if you can give me a hand. I update my codes and explain what I tried