# How to save the state of a toggle button after restarting app in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to save the state of my button after restarting the app. Everything works, the heart button turns red after clicking on it, but when I restart the app, it goes back to its default state. I would like to store it in my Firebase Firestore.

My Favorite button :

```
fun FavoriteButton(shoe : ShoeModel){

    val myviewModel : FirebaseFirestoreVM =
        viewModel(LocalContext.current as ViewModelStoreOwner, key = shoe.shoeName)

    val isFavorite = myviewModel.isFavorite

    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isFavorite.value ,
        onCheckedChange = {
            isFavorite.value = !isFavorite.value
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = if (isFavorite.value) {
                Icons.Filled.Favorite
            } else {
                Icons.Filled.FavoriteBorder
            }, contentDescription = null, tint = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        )
    }

    if (isFavorite.value) {
        myviewModel.addToDatabase(shoe)
    }

}
```

My ViewModel

```
  val isFavorite : MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun addToDatabase(shoe : ShoeModel){
        val obj = ShoeModel(
            shoe.shoeName,
            shoe.shoeImage,
            shoe.shoeDescription,
            shoe.shoePrice,
            shoe.shoeFrontSide,
            shoe.shoeBackSide,
            shoe.shoeSide,
            shoe.isFavorite
        )
        db.collection("shoes").document(shoe.shoeName).set(obj)
    }
```

Comment: You are assigning default value of `isFavorite` to false, in `viewmodel`. So every time app starts it picks it.
You can initialise the value of `isFavorite` by iterating the `db` collection, whether corresponding `shoe` exists or not.
Do not iterate `db` for every `FavoriteButton` look for a efficient way, or copy the data set you retrieved initially into the `viewmodel`s local variable [if that is possible].

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can achieve it?

Comment: Example for...?

Answer (score 1):

> Everything works, the heart button turns red after clicking on it, but when I restart the app, it goes back to its default state.

That works as expected because any time a state is updated the recomposition takes place. And that's the expected behavior since Jetpack Compose is declarative and the only way to update the UI is by calling the same composable with new arguments.

If you set a default value to a state and then change it according to the new value of the toggle button, it will work, but it will reset to the default value as soon as you restart the application. So in this case you should find a data structure that survives applications restarts. So you either use a local structure like [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) or [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences). However, none of them survives application uninstalls.

> I would like to store it in my Firebase Firestore.

That's an even better idea. Storing data in the Cloud, it's always a solution to go ahead with. Why? Because no matter what happens with the app, the data will always be present there. I have answered a related question a few weeks ago in which I explained how you can preserve the state of two radio buttons in real-time. The solution will also work for a toggle button:

- [Save and update radiobutton response correctly java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73735957/save-and-update-radiobutton-response-correctly-java)

Comment: I switched to Room DB now so i can save it locally? I'm struggling to do it. Do you have any example with Room?

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RoomJetpackCompose).

Comment: Hey BMB. Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the state of your button in a ViewModel and ViewModels are always destroyed when their host Activity is destroyed (if you didn't mess up and create a memory leak). When you shut down your app, all Activities including the one hosting that ViewModel will be destroyed. So that state, along with everything stored in the memory allocated to your ViewModel by the Android OS will be gone. ViewModels are designed to follow a lifecycle so they don't hog memory and computational resources when not in use.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle

Not only will an app restart destroy a ViewModel, but calling onDestroy() for its host Activity when we are not using that part of the app will as well. The Android OS can actually do this at any time! So never store anything that needs to be remembered permanently or long term in lifecycle aware components like Activities, Fragments, or ViewModels and especially not UI components. If the Android OS is low on memory and needs to kill that component, your state is gone!

You need to store state in a persistent structure like DataStore or Room
if you want it to survive an app restart. These components are designed to persistently store and access things in memory effectively and efficiently.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room